# PHP preg_replace string within variables

Tags: php, preg-replace, template-engine

I am using PHP 7.2.4, I want to make a template engine project,
I try to use preg_replace to change the variable in the string,
the code is here:

```
<?php
$lang = array(
    'hello' => 'Hello {$username}',
    'error_info' => 'Error Information : {$message}',
    'admin_denied' => '{$current_user} are not Administrator',
);

$username = 'Guest';
$current_user = 'Empty';
$message = 'You are not member !';

$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\{(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/', 'test', $string);

function test($matches)
{
    return '<?php echo '.$matches[1].'; ?>';
}

echo $new_string;
```

But it just show me

```
Hello , how are you?
```

It automatically remove the variable...

Update:
here is var_dump:

```
D:\Wamp\www\t.php:5:string 'Hello <?php echo $username; ?>, how are you?' (length=44)
```

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: [This is an example how you can do it](https://ideone.com/VXWdgB). Define an associative array rather than separate variables, and use it to replace matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes ! thanks you very much~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use create an associative array with keys (your variables) and values (their values), and then capture the variable part after `$` and use it to check in the `preg_replace_callback` callback function if there is a key named as the found capture. If yes, replace with the corresponding value, else, replace with the match to put it back where it was found.

Here is an [example code in PHP](https://ideone.com/VXWdgB):

```
$values = array('username'=>'AAAAAA', 'lastname'=>'Smith');
$string = 'Hello {$username}, how are you?';
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)}/', function($m) use ($values) {
        return 'Hello <?php echo ' . (!empty($values[$m[1]]) ? $values[$m[1]] : $m[0]) . '; ?>';
    }, $string);

var_dump($new_string);
```

Output:

```
string(47) "Hello Hello <?php echo AAAAAA; ?>, how are you?"
```

Note the pattern charnge, I moved the parentheses after `$`:

```
\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)}
    ^                                        ^
```

Actually, you may even shorten it to

```
\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*)}
                        ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
<?php
    $string = 'Hello {$username}, how are you?';
    $username = 'AAAAAA';
    $new_string = preg_replace('/\{(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/', $username, $string);
    echo $new_string;
```

The result is:

```
Hello AAAAAA, how are you?
```

The more simple way would be to just write

```
<?php
$username = 'AAAAAA';
$string = 'Hello '.$username.', how are you?';
```

Comment: No, I want to make an template engine class, the variable's name should change sometimes, so I need to let it can be `Hello <?php echo $username; ?>, how are you?`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of keeping it simple so I would use str_replace since it will also change all instances which may come in handy as you go forward.

```
$string = 'Hello {$username}, how are you?';
$username = 'AAAAAA';
echo str_replace('{$username}',$username,$string);
```

Comment: I am using it in my template engine project, the variables will be too much to write all variables with str_replace function